# Why it Lost text when export graphics?

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, rotation

I want to export graphics which has a **text** object, but it will lose the text when given a special rotate angle.

I have an angle list to show different text on the graphics, here only give a simple codes example (only show one text label).

```
angles2 = {{0., 0.05922829252191935`}};
labels = {"AAAAAA"};
names = Rotate[
   Text[Style[labels[[1]], Red, 20], 
    1.1*{1.0995176865382061`, 0.032570799647401755`}, {0, 0}], 
   Mean[angles2[[1]]] - \[Pi]/2];
gg = Graphics[{names, Opacity[0.5], Red, Circle[], Rectangle[]}, 
  ImageSize -> 200]
Export["xxx.pdf", gg]
```

[image]

I guess it has something to do with the rotation angle parameter given in the **Rotate** function, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: As far as I know, this phenomenon also appears in exported `.eps` files

Comment: right-click and save as pdf or export as png...MMA has a lot of problems when exporting graphics as vectors (pdf or eps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `Rotate` on the text directly

```
angles2 = {{0., 0.05922829252191935`}};
labels = {"AAAAAA"};
names = Text[
   Style[Rotate[labels[[1]], Mean[angles2[[1]]] - \[Pi]/2], Red, 20], 
   1.1*{1.0995176865382061`, 0.032570799647401755`}, {0, 0}];
gg = Graphics[{names, Opacity[0.5], Red, Circle[], Rectangle[]}, 
  ImageSize -> 200]
Export["xxx.pdf", gg]
```